# Customizable 3D "growing" Avatars within Unity

Tags: unity, models, character, avatar

I'm working on a project that allows the user to pick their personal avatar (change faces/body settings/etc), and then have child/adult versions of those.  Ideally, they will allow an age progression from Age 3 - Age 100 (or something).

I've built an [HTML5 page](https://rawgit.com/jaycrossler/avatar/master/index.html) with something conceptually like what I want ([github repo here](https://github.com/jaycrossler/avatar/)), but obviously I'm looking for a system that works within Unity3D for fully animated avatars.

It *seems* that a possible solution is [UMA2 (with the ingame avatar creator)](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/50237), but there's very little documentation and I can't find any "getting started guides online".  It also seems to have a DNA system that I could use for having parents have representative children, but can't find details.  There is a [YouTube video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkDHFObfS19wRJ9vvaDTwCe-zRPv9jI25) that I'm going through which seems quite good, but I haven't yet seen if there's anything to create children procedurally and how that would work.

Does anyone know whether the Unity team recommends this system or another one or what their roadmap is.  I see some UMA tools look like they're discontinued, some posts say they don't work with latest versions of unity, etc... but no ground-truth.

My current plan is to just buy a bunch of UMA stuff and slowly learn it through Trial and Error, but would appreciate if anyone has a good analysis of this area that they can share.

Note: I'm familiar with Makehuman and Adobe's Mixamo (both awesome and things I've spent a lot of time studying), but I am looking for something in-game to allow people to grow and evolve over time.  Bonus points if I can have 20 generations of marriages/children that show genetic traits passing down the line.  I've built support for that into the HTML5 system above, but not sure if it exists in the 3d space.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I edited post, and it looks like changes were voted to proceed.  How best to unlock this question?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into character customiation with blend shapes.  [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypRhJAfJXAc) youtube tutorial covers how to set it up. Now for a simple DNA System all that you will need is to encode all the values of the blend shapes in some sort of string or hash for both parents and generate a new onefor the child based on the parents. This will "pass" down stuff like nose shape, cheek widht, height etc.